# missing requirement osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xml.security.signature)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am upgrading my Apache POI libraries from 3.9 to 4.0.1, also using org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi. which has many required dependencies. I've been able to tackle most of them, I cannot find the Maven import for 
org.apache.xml.security.signature, for POM and Features.xml. something like:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xml</groupId>
      <artifactId>security.signature</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

updated POM and Features.xml

```
<!-- Java Apache POI Excel dependencies -->      
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0_1</version>  <!-- 3.9_2, 3.14_1 -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>  <!-- 3.9, 3.14-->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
  <version>1.18</version>
</dependency>

<feature>camel-core</feature>
<feature>camel-blueprint</feature>
<feature>camel-csv</feature>
<feature>camel-sql</feature>
<feature>camel-jdbc</feature>
<feature>camel-velocity</feature>
<feature>camel-xmlbeans</feature>

    <bundle start-level="60">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j/1.6.1_5</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="61">wrap:mvn:org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/4.0.1$DynamicImport-package=*</bundle> <!-- 3.9, 3.14 $DynamicImport-package=*-->
    <bundle start-level="61">wrap:mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="62">wrap:mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.18</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="63">wrap:mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.6.1</bundle>

    <bundle start-level="65">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi/4.0.0_1</bundle>  <!-- 3.9_2 3.13_1 3.14-->
```

OSGI dependency resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who care or run in to this issue, currently there are no servicemix poi bundles that successfully run in OSGI karaf container.  you will need to create your own POI bundle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ge.ip.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-bundle</artifactId>
<version>3.1.7</version>

<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>POI OSGi-Bundle</name>

<description>This OSGi bundle wraps poi, poi-ooxml, poi-ooxml-schemas and poi-scratchpad jar files.</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
<!--     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.virtuald</groupId>
        <artifactId>curvesapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.06</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Export-Package>
                    org.apache.poi.*;-split-package:=merge-first
                </Export-Package>
                    <!--
                    One important thing to note: if you are not exporting a package, you add it to the Private-Package instruction.
                    Otherwise, the classes inside the package will not be copied to your bundle, as the default value of this instruction is empty.
                    ;-split-package:=merge-first,com.graphbuilder.curve  || com.graphbuilder.geom, schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel.*
                    -->
                    <Private-Package>
                        org.apache.commons.*,
                        org.apache.xmlbeans.*,
                        com.graphbuilder.curve.*,
                        com.graphbuilder.geom.*,
                        com.graphbuilder.math.*,
                        com.graphbuilder.org.apache.harmony.awt.gl.*
                    </Private-Package>
                    <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                    <!-- <Import-Package>*</Import-Package> -->
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <id>copy-dependencies</id>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
     </plugin>
 </plugins>

</build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this is not osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xml.security.signature

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
  <artifactId>ooxml-security</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

    <bundle start-level="64">wrap:mvn:org.apache.poi/ooxml-security/1.1</bundle>
```

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-security/1.1/jar

MANIFEST showing only imports

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1543768929539
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_131
Built-By: jbonofre
Bundle-Description: This OSGi bundle wraps poi, poi-contrib, poi-ooxml
 , poi-ooxml-schemas and poi-scratchpad 4.0.0 jar files.
Bundle-DocURL: http://www.apache.org/
Bundle-License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: poi
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi
Bundle-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Bundle-Version: 4.0.0.1
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin

Import-Package: com.sun.javadoc;resolution:=optional,com.sun.tools.jav
 adoc;resolution:=optional,org.apache.crimson.jaxp;resolution:=optiona
 l,org.apache.tools.ant;resolution:=optional,org.apache.tools.ant.task
 defs;resolution:=optional,org.apache.tools.ant.types;resolution:=opti
 onal,org.bouncycastle.asn1;resolution:=optional,org.bouncycastle.asn1
 .cmp;resolution:=optional,org.bouncycastle.asn1.nist;resolution:=opti
 onal,org.bouncycastle.asn1.ocsp;resolution:=optional,org.bouncycastle
 .asn1.x500;resolution:=optional,org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509;resolution
 :=optional,org.bouncycastle.cert;resolution:=optional,org.bouncycastl
 e.cert.jcajce;resolution:=optional,org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp;resolut
 ion:=optional,org.bouncycastle.cms;resolution:=optional,org.bouncycas
 tle.cms.bc;resolution:=optional,org.bouncycastle.operator;resolution:
 =optional,org.bouncycastle.operator.bc;resolution:=optional,org.bounc
 ycastle.tsp;resolution:=optional,org.bouncycastle.util;resolution:=op
 tional,org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math;resolutio
 n:=optional,org.openxmlformats.schemas.schemaLibrary.x2006.main;resol
 ution:=optional,repackage;resolution:=optional,org.apache.jcp.xml.dsi
 g.internal.dom;resolution:=optional,org.apache.xml.resolver;resolutio
 n:=optional,org.apache.xml.resolver.tools;resolution:=optional,org.ap
 ache.xml.security;resolution:=optional,org.apache.xml.security.c14n;r
 esolution:=optional,org.apache.xml.security.utils;resolution:=optiona
 l,com.graphbuilder.curve;resolution:=optional,com.graphbuilder.geom;r
 esolution:=optional,com.microsoft.schemas.vml;resolution:=optional,ja
 vax.crypto,javax.crypto.spec,javax.imageio,javax.imageio.metadata,jav
 ax.imageio.stream,javax.security.auth.x500,javax.swing,javax.swing.bo
 rder,javax.swing.plaf,javax.swing.table,javax.swing.tree,javax.xml.bi
 nd,javax.xml.bind.annotation,javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters,javax
 .xml.crypto,javax.xml.crypto.dom,javax.xml.crypto.dsig,javax.xml.cryp
 to.dsig.dom,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec,
 javax.xml.namespace,javax.xml.parsers,javax.xml.stream,javax.xml.stre
 am.events,javax.xml.stream.util,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transfo
 rm.dom,javax.xml.transform.stream,javax.xml.validation,javax.xml.xpat
 h,org.apache.commons.codec.digest;version="[1.10,2)",org.apache.commo
 ns.collections4;version="[4.2,5)",org.apache.commons.collections4.bid
 imap;version="[4.2,5)",org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators;vers
 ion="[4.2,5)",org.apache.commons.collections4.multimap;version="[4.2,
 5)",org.apache.commons.compress.archivers;version="[1.18,2)",org.apac
 he.commons.compress.archivers.zip;version="[1.18,2)",org.apache.commo
 ns.compress.utils;version="[1.18,2)",org.apache.commons.logging,org.a
 pache.commons.math3.exception,org.apache.commons.math3.linear,org.apa
 che.poi;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.common.usermodel;version="[4
 .0,5)",org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.fonts;version="[4.0,5)",org.ap
 ache.poi.ddf;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.extractor;version="[4.0
 ,5)",org.apache.poi.hdgf;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hdgf.chunks
 ;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hdgf.exceptions;version="[4.0,5)",o
 rg.apache.poi.hdgf.extractor;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hdgf.po
 inters;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hdgf.streams;version="[4.0,5)
 ",org.apache.poi.hemf.hemfplus.record;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.po
 i.hemf.record;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hmef;version="[4.0,5)"
 ,org.apache.poi.hmef.attribute;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hpbf;
 version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hpbf.extractor;version="[4.0,5)",org
 .apache.poi.hpbf.model;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hpbf.model.qc
 bits;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hpsf;version="[4.0,5)",org.apac
 he.poi.hpsf.extractor;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hpsf.wellknown
 ;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hslf.blip;version="[4.0,5)",org.apa
 che.poi.hslf.exceptions;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hslf.model;v
 ersion="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hslf.model.textproperties;version="[4
 .0,5)",org.apache.poi.hslf.record;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hs
 lf.usermodel;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hslf.util;version="[4.0
 ,5)",org.apache.poi.hsmf;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hsmf.dataty
 pes;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hsmf.exceptions;version="[4.0,5)
 ",org.apache.poi.hsmf.extractor;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hsmf
 .parsers;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf;version="[4.0,5)",org.
 apache.poi.hssf.eventusermodel;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf.
 eventusermodel.dummyrecord;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf.extr
 actor;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf.model;version="[4.0,5)",o
 rg.apache.poi.hssf.record;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf.recor
 d.aggregates;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf.record.cf;version=
 "[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf.record.chart;version="[4.0,5)",org.apac
 he.poi.hssf.record.common;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf.recor
 d.cont;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf.record.crypto;version="[
 4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf.record.pivottable;version="[4.0,5)",org.a
 pache.poi.hssf.usermodel;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf.usermo
 del.helpers;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hssf.util;version="[4.0,
 5)",org.apache.poi.hwmf.draw;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hwmf.re
 cord;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hwmf.usermodel;version="[4.0,5)
 ",org.apache.poi.hwpf;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter
 ;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor;version="[4.0,5)",or
 g.apache.poi.hwpf.model;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.i
 o;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hwpf.model.types;version="[4.0,5)"
 ,org.apache.poi.hwpf.sprm;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.hwpf.userm
 odel;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.ooxml.util;version="[4.0,5)",or
 g.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.op
 enxml4j.opc;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal;v
 ersion="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers;ve
 rsion="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.unmarshallers;v
 ersion="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util;version="[4.0,5)",org.
 apache.poi.poifs.common;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt;
 version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.binaryrc4;version="[4.0,
 5)",org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.cryptoapi;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache
 .poi.poifs.crypt.standard;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.poifs.cryp
 t.xor;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.poifs.dev;version="[4.0,5)",or
 g.apache.poi.poifs.eventfilesystem;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.p
 oifs.filesystem;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.poifs.nio;version="[
 4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.poifs.property;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.po
 i.poifs.storage;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.sl.draw;version="[4.
 0,5)",org.apache.poi.sl.draw.binding;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi
 .sl.draw.geom;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.sl.extractor;version="
 [4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.sl.image;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.sl.
 usermodel;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.ss;version="[4.0,5)",org.a
 pache.poi.ss.extractor;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.ss.format;ver
 sion="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.ss.formula;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache
 .poi.ss.formula.atp;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.ss.formula.const
 ant;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval;version="[4.0,5)
 ",org.apache.poi.ss.formula.function;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi
 .ss.formula.functions;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg
 ;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf;version="[4.0,5)",or
 g.apache.poi.ss.usermodel;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.ss.usermod
 el.charts;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.contrib;versi
 on="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.helpers;version="[4.0,5)",or
 g.apache.poi.ss.util;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.util;version="[
 4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.
 xdgf.exceptions;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.xdgf.extractor;versi
 on="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.xdgf.geom;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.po
 i.xdgf.usermodel.section;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.xdgf.usermo
 del.section.geometry;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.xdgf.usermodel.
 shape;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.xdgf.usermodel.shape.exception
 s;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.xdgf.xml;version="[4.0,5)",org.apa
 che.poi.xssf;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.xssf.binary;version="[4
 .0,5)",org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi
 .xssf.usermodel.charts;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.xssf.usermode
 l.extensions;version="[4.0,5)",org.apache.poi.xssf.util;version="[4.0
 ,5)",org.apache.xml.security.signature,org.ietf.jgss,org.w3c.dom,org.
 w3c.dom.events,org.w3c.dom.ls,org.xml.sax,org.xml.sax.ext,org.xml.sax
 .helpers,junit.framework;resolution:=optional
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-3.2.0.201605172007
```

Comment: this is not org.apache.xml.security.signature needed by org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi

Comment: does anyone know anyone that has successfully instrumented org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi / 4.0.0_1 ??? please share how.  I cannot resolve all the dependencies.  thank you

Comment: for those who care or run in to this issue, currently there are no servicemix poi bundles that successfully run in OSGI karaf container.  you will need to create your own POI bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully build and deploy to OSGI karaf container using

org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi 4.0.1_1

FEATURES XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.0.0">
  <feature name="fadec-application" version="1.0.0" description="Delta FADEC Route and dependencies">
    <feature>camel-core</feature>
    <feature>camel-blueprint</feature>
    <feature>camel-csv</feature>
    <feature>camel-sql</feature>
    <feature>camel-jdbc</feature>
    <feature>camel-velocity</feature>
    <feature>camel-xmlbeans</feature>
    <feature>camel-jaxb</feature>
    <bundle start-level="60">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j/1.6.1_5</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="60">wrap:mvn:org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/3.0.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="62">wrap:mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.3</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="62">wrap:mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.18</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="62">wrap:mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.6.1</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="62">wrap:mvn:commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="62">wrap:mvn:com.github.virtuald/curvesapi/1.06</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="63">wrap:mvn:org.apache.poi/ooxml-security/1.1</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="63">wrap:mvn:org.apache.santuario/xmlsec/2.0.10</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="65">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi/4.0.1_1</bundle> <!-- 3.9_2 -->
    <bundle>mvn:com.ibm.msg.client.osgi/osgi-jms/7.5.0.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.ibm.msg.client.osgi/osgi-wmq-prereq/7.5.0.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.ibm.msg.client.osgi/osgi-nls/7.5.0.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.ibm.msg.client.osgi/osgi-wmq-nls/7.5.0.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.ibm.msg.client.osgi/osgi-wmq/7.5.0.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.ibm.msg.client.osgi/osgi-commonservices-j2se/7.5.0.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.ibm.msg.client.osgi/jms-prereq/7.5.0.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.ibm.mq.osgi/osgi-directip/7.5.0.2</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">wrap:mvn:com.enterprisemath/em-utils/2.4.0</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="80">wrap:mvn:mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.45</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="84">wrap:mvn:com.mchange/mchange-commons-java/0.2.11</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="85">wrap:mvn:com.mchange/c3p0/0.9.5.2$Bundle-SymbolicName=c3p0-0.9.5.2&amp;Import-package=*;resolution:=optional;version=0</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="85">wrap:mvn:org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.0.4.RELEASE$Import-package=com.mysql.jdbc;resolution:=optional;version=0,javax.sql;resolution:=optional;version=0,org.apache.commons.logging;resolution:=optional;version=0,org.springframework.util;resolution:=0;version=0</bundle>
    <bundle start-level="90">mvn:com.ge.ip.infra/delta-fadec-prod/3.0.1-SNAPSHOT</bundle>
  </feature>
</features>
```

POM

```
    <!-- Java Apache POI Excel dependencies 4.0.1_1 -->      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1_1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
      <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.virtuald</groupId>
        <artifactId>curvesapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.06</version>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.enterprisemath</groupId>
        <artifactId>em-utils</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>ooxml-security</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- Java Apache POI Excel dependencies 4.0.1_1 -->
```